# SSIS ignoring Text Qualifier - double quotes remain in one column

Tags: ssis

I am attempting to import a file that looks like the following:

```
"RTSTAT","DATE","      BUS_LINE      ","AMOUNT","LN_CODE","TEAM"  
"0646540210","10/04/11  ","   P   ",  99900.00,"0010101","0098765"
"0940365400","03/30/12  ","   P   ",  88800.00,"0020202","0085464"
```

I have the Text Qualifier in the Connection Manager set to "

Although the data for the TEAM column still shows the double-quotes in the Preview.

When I run the package, the source file in the DataFlow errors with this:

```
Error: 0xC0202055 at Data Flow Task, Source - VFE3007M_DETAIL_csv [1]: 
The column delimiter for column "TEAM      " was not found.
Error: 0xC0202091 at Data Flow Task, Source - VFE3007M_DETAIL_csv [1]: 
An error occurred while skipping data rows.
Error: 0xC0047038 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.
The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - VFE3007M_DETAIL_csv" (1) 
returned error code 0xC0202091.
```

If I use NotePad and remove all double-quotes, the file works.  Although that is not ideal.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to remove Double-Quotes first step in SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817930/need-to-remove-double-quotes-first-step-in-ssis)

Comment: That one was mine, and is Closed.  I didn't ask the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Connection Manager// Advanced section on the left panel. You will see that column names have double-quotes and spaces. Clean-up all the column names.

Comment: Anoop, I cleaned up the leading and trailing spaces in Connection Manager.  There weren't any quotes shown there.

Unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: `SSIS - Version 11.0.6020.0`, it helped me to change `TextQualified` to `True` in Flat File Connection Manager Editor where Text qualifier is `(")`.